# Debugging with XDebug and Netbeans from Windows to Ubuntu remote server

Tags: netbeans, xdebug

I'm trying to debug a Drupal 7 app with Xdebug. My app resides remotely in a server with Ubuntu running Apache.

In Netabeans, I started a proyect with "Application From Remote Server", connected with SFTP.

In the remote server I have installed Xdebug as zend_extension, also i configured xdebug.remote_connect_back=1, xdebug.remote_autostart=1, etc... I've tried everything with no luck.

The log from Xdebug has entries like this one:

Log opened at 2014-12-24 13:01:31
I: Checking remote connect back address.
I: Remote address found, connecting to 181.175.73.24:9000
E: Time-out connecting to client. :-(
Log closed at 2014-12-24 13:01:32

Based on the log it seems that my computer is not visible from outside on port 9000. But port 9000 in my laptop is opened, listening, with Netbeans, that's what happens when a debug sessions starts.

I think it's a problem with my ISP. My IP is not only for me, so I can't manage it's ports or other configuration. I think my PC is not visible from outside.

So, the question is, how can I avoid this limitation? What could I debug my APP from my computer on a remote server?

Every answer is welcome. Using a program, using a service, both... I tried using pagekite but honestly I couldn't find a configuration that works for me.

Thanks everyone.

PD: I don't want Xdebug alternatives that don't do step by step debugging.

PD2: My Xdebug config is attached.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

remote_connect_back won't do it for you, it just tries to connect to the public ip, it's nothing magic.
Can you ssh on the remote server ? You might want to try   **port forwarding** over a **reverse ssh tunnel**.

Full details from the creator of xdebug: 
http://derickrethans.nl/debugging-with-xdebug-and-firewalls.html